# How to set value of slide range to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to set value of slide range to php variable ?

i want to set value of slide range in to `$amount`

http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 700,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?PHP echo $amount; ?>">
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question: do you want the initial value of the slider to be set to $amount? Or are you trying to send the value of the slider to the server and store it in $amount?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the slider with a php variable in your script tag the same way you set the value `$amount` in the input field (by wrapping the variable in `<?php echo ... ?>`. You can only do this when the server is rendering your page though, not after its been served to the user.